# Cross compiling from macOS to Windows not working with rust

Tags: rust, mingw, ld, mingw-w64, rust-cargo

I ran `cargo build --release --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu --verbose`, and I get this error:

```sh
jackprograms@Jacks-Air calcead % cargo build --release --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu --verbose
   Compiling memchr v2.4.1
   Compiling ucd-trie v0.1.3
   Compiling regex-syntax v0.6.25
   Compiling cc v1.0.72
   Compiling libc v0.2.108
   Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
     Running `rustc --crate-name build_script_build --edition=2018 /Users/jackprograms/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/memchr-2.4.1/build.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=183eab6bce46a298 -C extra-filename=-183eab6bce46a298 --out-dir '/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/build/memchr-183eab6bce46a298' -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' --cap-lints allow`
     Running `rustc --crate-name regex_syntax --edition=2018 /Users/jackprograms/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/regex-syntax-0.6.25/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="unicode"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-age"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-bool"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-case"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-gencat"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-perl"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-script"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-segment"' -C metadata=70b5868cc9479383 -C extra-filename=-70b5868cc9479383 --out-dir '/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' --cap-lints allow`
     Running `rustc --crate-name ucd_trie --edition=2018 /Users/jackprograms/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ucd-trie-0.1.3/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=728d610cce8f5588 -C extra-filename=-728d610cce8f5588 --out-dir '/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' --cap-lints allow`
     Running `rustc --crate-name cc --edition=2018 /Users/jackprograms/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cc-1.0.72/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off -C metadata=9ff1491c436d28d9 -C extra-filename=-9ff1491c436d28d9 --out-dir '/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' --cap-lints allow`
     Running `rustc --crate-name build_script_build /Users/jackprograms/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libc-0.2.108/build.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=90c5cb75c3345e17 -C extra-filename=-90c5cb75c3345e17 --out-dir '/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/build/libc-90c5cb75c3345e17' -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' --cap-lints allow`
     Running `rustc --crate-name lazy_static /Users/jackprograms/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/lazy_static-1.4.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off -C metadata=d58bb36d0d38a9ff -C extra-filename=-d58bb36d0d38a9ff --out-dir '/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' --cap-lints allow`
   Compiling pest v2.1.3
     Running `rustc --crate-name pest /Users/jackprograms/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/pest-2.1.3/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off -C metadata=db52f8702561d0e0 -C extra-filename=-db52f8702561d0e0 --out-dir '/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' --extern 'ucd_trie=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps/libucd_trie-728d610cce8f5588.rmeta' --cap-lints allow`
     Running `/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/build/memchr-183eab6bce46a298/build-script-build`
     Running `/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/build/libc-90c5cb75c3345e17/build-script-build`
     Running `rustc --crate-name memchr --edition=2018 /Users/jackprograms/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/memchr-2.4.1/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=c4bc2607aa6eb643 -C extra-filename=-c4bc2607aa6eb643 --out-dir '/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' --cap-lints allow`
     Running `rustc --crate-name libc /Users/jackprograms/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libc-0.2.108/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=d5b765a7cdcaf344 -C extra-filename=-d5b765a7cdcaf344 --out-dir '/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps' --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps' -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' --cap-lints allow --cfg freebsd11 --cfg libc_priv_mod_use --cfg libc_union --cfg libc_const_size_of --cfg libc_align --cfg libc_core_cvoid --cfg libc_packedN --cfg libc_cfg_target_vendor --cfg libc_non_exhaustive --cfg libc_ptr_addr_of`
   Compiling aho-corasick v0.7.18
     Running `rustc --crate-name aho_corasick --edition=2018 /Users/jackprograms/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/aho-corasick-0.7.18/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=e80773c26ecb6f64 -C extra-filename=-e80773c26ecb6f64 --out-dir '/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' --extern 'memchr=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps/libmemchr-c4bc2607aa6eb643.rmeta' --cap-lints allow`
   Compiling semver-parser v0.10.2
     Running `rustc --crate-name semver_parser --edition=2018 /Users/jackprograms/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/semver-parser-0.10.2/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off -C metadata=3e6f603ec03c9fee -C extra-filename=-3e6f603ec03c9fee --out-dir '/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' --extern 'pest=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps/libpest-db52f8702561d0e0.rmeta' --cap-lints allow`
   Compiling semver v0.11.0
     Running `rustc --crate-name semver /Users/jackprograms/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/semver-0.11.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off --cfg 'feature="default"' -C metadata=86233a7447942907 -C extra-filename=-86233a7447942907 --out-dir '/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' --extern 'semver_parser=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps/libsemver_parser-3e6f603ec03c9fee.rmeta' --cap-lints allow`
   Compiling regex v1.5.4
     Running `rustc --crate-name regex --edition=2018 /Users/jackprograms/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/regex-1.5.4/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off --cfg 'feature="aho-corasick"' --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="memchr"' --cfg 'feature="perf"' --cfg 'feature="perf-cache"' --cfg 'feature="perf-dfa"' --cfg 'feature="perf-inline"' --cfg 'feature="perf-literal"' --cfg 'feature="std"' --cfg 'feature="unicode"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-age"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-bool"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-case"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-gencat"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-perl"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-script"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-segment"' -C metadata=97cd38d7cc1009db -C extra-filename=-97cd38d7cc1009db --out-dir '/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' --extern 'aho_corasick=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps/libaho_corasick-e80773c26ecb6f64.rmeta' --extern 'memchr=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps/libmemchr-c4bc2607aa6eb643.rmeta' --extern 'regex_syntax=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps/libregex_syntax-70b5868cc9479383.rmeta' --cap-lints allow`
   Compiling llvm-sys v130.0.0
     Running `rustc --crate-name build_script_build /Users/jackprograms/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/llvm-sys-130.0.0/build.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off -C metadata=55787fb29ebe8264 -C extra-filename=-55787fb29ebe8264 --out-dir '/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/build/llvm-sys-55787fb29ebe8264' -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' --extern 'cc=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps/libcc-9ff1491c436d28d9.rlib' --extern 'lazy_static=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps/liblazy_static-d58bb36d0d38a9ff.rlib' --extern 'regex=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps/libregex-97cd38d7cc1009db.rlib' --extern 'semver=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps/libsemver-86233a7447942907.rlib' --cap-lints allow`
     Running `/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/build/llvm-sys-55787fb29ebe8264/build-script-build`
     Running `rustc --crate-name llvm_sys /Users/jackprograms/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/llvm-sys-130.0.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=7ad3b9bf231428ce -C extra-filename=-7ad3b9bf231428ce --out-dir '/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps' --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps' -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' --extern 'libc=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/liblibc-d5b765a7cdcaf344.rmeta' --cap-lints allow -L 'native=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/build/llvm-sys-b9ec6c460bcb178e/out' -L native=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/13.0.0_1/lib -l static=targetwrappers -l static=LLVMWindowsManifest -l static=LLVMXRay -l static=LLVMLibDriver -l static=LLVMDlltoolDriver -l static=LLVMCoverage -l static=LLVMLineEditor -l static=LLVMXCoreDisassembler -l static=LLVMXCoreCodeGen -l static=LLVMXCoreDesc -l static=LLVMXCoreInfo -l static=LLVMX86Disassembler -l static=LLVMX86AsmParser -l static=LLVMX86CodeGen -l static=LLVMX86Desc -l static=LLVMX86Info -l static=LLVMWebAssemblyDisassembler -l static=LLVMWebAssemblyAsmParser -l static=LLVMWebAssemblyCodeGen -l static=LLVMWebAssemblyDesc -l static=LLVMWebAssemblyUtils -l static=LLVMWebAssemblyInfo -l static=LLVMSystemZDisassembler -l static=LLVMSystemZAsmParser -l static=LLVMSystemZCodeGen -l static=LLVMSystemZDesc -l static=LLVMSystemZInfo -l static=LLVMSparcDisassembler -l static=LLVMSparcAsmParser -l static=LLVMSparcCodeGen -l static=LLVMSparcDesc -l static=LLVMSparcInfo -l static=LLVMRISCVDisassembler -l static=LLVMRISCVAsmParser -l static=LLVMRISCVCodeGen -l static=LLVMRISCVDesc -l static=LLVMRISCVInfo -l static=LLVMPowerPCDisassembler -l static=LLVMPowerPCAsmParser -l static=LLVMPowerPCCodeGen -l static=LLVMPowerPCDesc -l static=LLVMPowerPCInfo -l static=LLVMNVPTXCodeGen -l static=LLVMNVPTXDesc -l static=LLVMNVPTXInfo -l static=LLVMMSP430Disassembler -l static=LLVMMSP430AsmParser -l static=LLVMMSP430CodeGen -l static=LLVMMSP430Desc -l static=LLVMMSP430Info -l static=LLVMMipsDisassembler -l static=LLVMMipsAsmParser -l static=LLVMMipsCodeGen -l static=LLVMMipsDesc -l static=LLVMMipsInfo -l static=LLVMLanaiDisassembler -l static=LLVMLanaiCodeGen -l static=LLVMLanaiAsmParser -l static=LLVMLanaiDesc -l static=LLVMLanaiInfo -l static=LLVMHexagonDisassembler -l static=LLVMHexagonCodeGen -l static=LLVMHexagonAsmParser -l static=LLVMHexagonDesc -l static=LLVMHexagonInfo -l static=LLVMBPFDisassembler -l static=LLVMBPFAsmParser -l static=LLVMBPFCodeGen -l static=LLVMBPFDesc -l static=LLVMBPFInfo -l static=LLVMAVRDisassembler -l static=LLVMAVRAsmParser -l static=LLVMAVRCodeGen -l static=LLVMAVRDesc -l static=LLVMAVRInfo -l static=LLVMARMDisassembler -l static=LLVMARMAsmParser -l static=LLVMARMCodeGen -l static=LLVMARMDesc -l static=LLVMARMUtils -l static=LLVMARMInfo -l static=LLVMAMDGPUDisassembler -l static=LLVMAMDGPUAsmParser -l static=LLVMAMDGPUCodeGen -l static=LLVMAMDGPUDesc -l static=LLVMAMDGPUUtils -l static=LLVMAMDGPUInfo -l static=LLVMAArch64Disassembler -l static=LLVMAArch64AsmParser -l static=LLVMAArch64CodeGen -l static=LLVMAArch64Desc -l static=LLVMAArch64Utils -l static=LLVMAArch64Info -l static=LLVMOrcJIT -l static=LLVMMCJIT -l static=LLVMJITLink -l static=LLVMInterpreter -l static=LLVMExecutionEngine -l static=LLVMRuntimeDyld -l static=LLVMOrcTargetProcess -l static=LLVMOrcShared -l static=LLVMDWP -l static=LLVMSymbolize -l static=LLVMDebugInfoPDB -l static=LLVMDebugInfoGSYM -l static=LLVMOption -l static=LLVMObjectYAML -l static=LLVMMCA -l static=LLVMMCDisassembler -l static=LLVMLTO -l static=LLVMCFGuard -l static=LLVMFrontendOpenACC -l static=LLVMExtensions -l static=Polly -l static=PollyISL -l static=LLVMPasses -l static=LLVMObjCARCOpts -l static=LLVMCoroutines -l static=LLVMipo -l static=LLVMInstrumentation -l static=LLVMVectorize -l static=LLVMLinker -l static=LLVMFrontendOpenMP -l static=LLVMDWARFLinker -l static=LLVMGlobalISel -l static=LLVMMIRParser -l static=LLVMAsmPrinter -l static=LLVMDebugInfoMSF -l static=LLVMDebugInfoDWARF -l static=LLVMSelectionDAG -l static=LLVMCodeGen -l static=LLVMIRReader -l static=LLVMAsmParser -l static=LLVMInterfaceStub -l static=LLVMFileCheck -l static=LLVMFuzzMutate -l static=LLVMTarget -l static=LLVMScalarOpts -l static=LLVMInstCombine -l static=LLVMAggressiveInstCombine -l static=LLVMTransformUtils -l static=LLVMBitWriter -l static=LLVMAnalysis -l static=LLVMProfileData -l static=LLVMObject -l static=LLVMTextAPI -l static=LLVMMCParser -l static=LLVMMC -l static=LLVMDebugInfoCodeView -l static=LLVMBitReader -l static=LLVMCore -l static=LLVMRemarks -l static=LLVMBitstreamReader -l static=LLVMBinaryFormat -l static=LLVMTableGen -l static=LLVMSupport -l static=LLVMDemangle -l dylib=m -l dylib=z -l dylib=curses -l dylib=xml2 -l dylib=c++`
   Compiling calcead v0.1.0 (/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead)
     Running `rustc --crate-name calcead --edition=2018 src/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=0b1ae7c97504e2d2 -C extra-filename=-0b1ae7c97504e2d2 --out-dir '/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps' --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps' -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' --extern 'llvm_sys=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/libllvm_sys-7ad3b9bf231428ce.rlib' -L 'native=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/build/llvm-sys-b9ec6c460bcb178e/out' -L native=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/13.0.0_1/lib`
error: linking with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--dynamicbase" "-Wl,--disable-auto-image-base" "-m64" "-Wl,--high-entropy-va" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/rsbegin.o" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/calcead-0b1ae7c97504e2d2.calcead.318shec0-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/calcead-0b1ae7c97504e2d2.calcead.318shec0-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/calcead-0b1ae7c97504e2d2.calcead.318shec0-cgu.10.rcgu.o" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/calcead-0b1ae7c97504e2d2.calcead.318shec0-cgu.11.rcgu.o" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/calcead-0b1ae7c97504e2d2.calcead.318shec0-cgu.12.rcgu.o" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/calcead-0b1ae7c97504e2d2.calcead.318shec0-cgu.13.rcgu.o" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/calcead-0b1ae7c97504e2d2.calcead.318shec0-cgu.14.rcgu.o" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/calcead-0b1ae7c97504e2d2.calcead.318shec0-cgu.15.rcgu.o" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/calcead-0b1ae7c97504e2d2.calcead.318shec0-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/calcead-0b1ae7c97504e2d2.calcead.318shec0-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/calcead-0b1ae7c97504e2d2.calcead.318shec0-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/calcead-0b1ae7c97504e2d2.calcead.318shec0-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/calcead-0b1ae7c97504e2d2.calcead.318shec0-cgu.6.rcgu.o" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/calcead-0b1ae7c97504e2d2.calcead.318shec0-cgu.7.rcgu.o" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/calcead-0b1ae7c97504e2d2.calcead.318shec0-cgu.8.rcgu.o" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/calcead-0b1ae7c97504e2d2.calcead.318shec0-cgu.9.rcgu.o" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/calcead-0b1ae7c97504e2d2.f12v57cfpm7j4i6.rcgu.o" "-L" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps" "-L" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps" "-L" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/build/llvm-sys-b9ec6c460bcb178e/out" "-L" "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/13.0.0_1/lib" "-L" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/libllvm_sys-7ad3b9bf231428ce.rlib" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/liblibc-d5b765a7cdcaf344.rlib" "-Wl,--start-group" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libstd-d78f8a012519ed00.rlib" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-d704a2ba1fc34dcb.rlib" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libobject-f99bf47714118316.rlib" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-d8dd5e215cc4d03a.rlib" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libgimli-1da59c07cf6613f0.rlib" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libstd_detect-f1d735e88bee19c3.rlib" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-705d4fb683e18dfb.rlib" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-93aabf6c5d54583b.rlib" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-2d940363809c49a7.rlib" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libunwind-628779988d844869.rlib" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-4315a10ecfe61904.rlib" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/liblibc-3e71c094dccece31.rlib" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/liballoc-693e00711df264d9.rlib" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-bb356fb080a8883b.rlib" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libcore-546a2082c15b3ef0.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-ed79ec76e7a93387.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lm" "-lz" "-lcurses" "-lxml2" "-lc++" "-lkernel32" "-lws2_32" "-ladvapi32" "-luserenv" "-lkernel32" "-lgcc_eh" "-l:libpthread.a" "-lmsvcrt" "-lmingwex" "-lmingw32" "-lgcc" "-lmsvcrt" "-luser32" "-lkernel32" "-Wl,--nxcompat" "-L" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib" "-o" "/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/calcead-0b1ae7c97504e2d2.exe" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-no-pie" "-Wl,-O1" "-nodefaultlibs" "/Users/jackprograms/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/rsend.o"
  = note: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mingw-w64/9.0.0_2/toolchain-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lz
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mingw-w64/9.0.0_2/toolchain-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lcurses
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mingw-w64/9.0.0_2/toolchain-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lxml2
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mingw-w64/9.0.0_2/toolchain-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/13.0.0_1/lib/libc++.a: error adding symbols: archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `calcead`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name calcead --edition=2018 src/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=0b1ae7c97504e2d2 -C extra-filename=-0b1ae7c97504e2d2 --out-dir '/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps' --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps' -L 'dependency=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/release/deps' --extern 'llvm_sys=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/libllvm_sys-7ad3b9bf231428ce.rlib' -L 'native=/Users/jackprograms/Documents/Rust Projects/calcead/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/build/llvm-sys-b9ec6c460bcb178e/out' -L native=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/13.0.0_1/lib` (exit status: 1)
```

It's some linker error that I cannot understand. The same error happens if I didn't add `--release`.

If I did `i686-pc-windows-gnu`, the same error about a "symbol" happens as well.

I already installed mingw in my macOS with homebrew (`brew install mingw-w32`), therefore that's not the problem.

What is this linker symbol error?

Comment: You need to install the mingw development versions of the libraries you use, here `zlib`, `curses` and `libxml2`. I don't know if they are available on homebrew or under what name.

Comment: @Jmb Do you know why they didn't come with mingw, and how do you know those are required? Homebrew seems to saying `zlib` and `libxml2` are already installed in the MacOS, so they have to be put in another path to not cause any issues.

Comment: Note that I don't have a Mac, so everything I say are just WAGs. I know they are required because that's what the various `x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -l...` messages mean. They didn't come with mingw because mingw is just the toolchain and can't include every possible additional library.

Comment: When homebrew says they are already installed, are you sure that the _mingw_ development versions are installed, not just the MacOS versions?

Comment: Here's what homebrew said:

```bash
zlib is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

For compilers to find zlib you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include"

For pkg-config to find zlib you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Comment: That sounds like this is a MacOS version of zlib, not the MingW version. You will need to install the MingW version, but I don't know how to do this on MacOS (on ArchLinux, I would just install "mingw-w64-zlib").

Comment: Homebrew is for installing things targetting the macOS platform. With MinGW you are targeting Windows, so you will need to get Windows development libraries another way or build from source also with MinGW. Make sure not to install over any macOS stuff or in paths your macOS points to (e.g. via `PATH` environment variable)